# How to disable text box value depending on other button Usage

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my view I have two fields: date of birth and age(radio button). My view code is

```
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DateofBirth)</td>
<td> @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.AgeGroup)</td>
```

When I click on DateofBirth

1. The age group radio button should be disabled and vice versa.
2. By calculating the age the radio button list should be selected.

How to achieve this using MVC4

Comment: please provide more info what you want?
like on what age you want to select the radio button?

Comment: You mean when you focus on the `DateOfBirth` textbox the radio buttons should be disabled? Or do you mean - disable them if any text is provided ?

Comment: if any text is provided

Comment: You can't use javascript? Or add a property to the model that is set in the controller or something and disables the buttons accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

this would be client side code, as the tag says jquery, i will give jquery

```
$("#DateOfBirth").on("click",function(){
$("#AgeGroup").hide();
});
```

and same goes for the other property, or you can change attributes to disable, but quicker and easier and cleaner to just hide